# What is such parameter called for a frequency to voltage converter

Tags: datasheet, converter

In a frequency to analog voltage converter what is the parameter which is related to the response of the conversion.

So for example I use [this](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/2902056_Ds.pdf) converter module and Im wondering how fast the change in the incoming pulse frequency has an effect on the change in output voltage.

What is such parameter called for a converter if there is such thing exists? (I cannot see in the module's datasheet such parameter)

Comment: Do you mean their step response specs?

Comment: What I mean is I set the conversion as 1Hz to 1200Hz will be converted to 0 to 10V. But I dont know how I can estimate a input freq  change from 100Hz to 150Hz in a second will affect the change in output voltage. Yes basically Im wondering the response or delay,

Answer (score 1):

Page 8 of the data sheet shows the 0-99% step response as <35mS, when the input frequency is above 500Hz. This means it's undefined below 500Hz, which is reasonable, as presumably the detector needs several cycles to settle, and so the response time is likely to increase.

This may or may not be exactly what you're after. Other definitions of a similar thing would be the latency (usually the time between the 50% point on the input change and the 50% point on the output change), the frequency response (be careful as the input is also a frequency, to not get confused), and the time constant (making an assumption that the response is first order).

Note that step responses are usually only specified to 90% of the final change, it's easier to measure that point with an oscilloscope than the 99% point. It sounds like they're trying to use 99% to mean 'fully settled', which it more or less is.

Comment: Does that mean the max delay is around 35ms?

Comment: Specs also say "< 35 ms (f > 500 Hz)" Does that mean below 500Hz the step response is less than 35ms?

Comment: @cm64 You should read/take specification points as literally as possible. That means **IF** the step is 500 Hz or more **THEN** the response time will be **less than 35 ms**. Basically nothing else is specified. So you cannot draw **any** conclusion about a step of less than 500 Hz.

Comment: @cm64 Updated the answer. It was a mistake to think it was obvious and so omit it the first time.